# ReferenceError: $output is not defined in javascript(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an API where I would like to get all users and then display them in some sort of table. However now I'm getting a `ReferenceError: $output is not defined` when running the code. I tried this out in another project and it doesn't give that error there.

My JavaScript code:

```
function displayData(data) {
    $('.content').empty();
    console.log(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $output += '<div>' + data[i].ContactName + '</div>';
        $(".content").append($output);
    }
}
```

Which I'm trying to output to this `div`:

```
<div class="content">   
</div>
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error while it is running without on another project. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Declare `$output = ''` at the beginning of function.

Comment: you must use var $output += '';

Comment: Oh gosh, I've looked at it for an hour and it was right under my nose...

Comment: @Tushar, can you write that as an answer so I can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer Below Fiddle..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqm6c0re/3/)

**JavaScript**

```
var $output = '';
var data = [{'ContactName':'ABC'},{'ContactName':'EFG'}]

$( document ).ready(function() {
   displayData(data);
});

function displayData(data){
    $('.content').empty();
    console.log(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        $output+= '<div>'+data[i].ContactName+'</div>';
        $(".content").append($output);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">   
</div>
```

Declare **$output** as a Variable.

```
var $output = '';
```